# Использование библиотек yandex

Tags: visual-studio-code, библиотеки

Использую API яндекс карт, можно ли как-то подключить библиотеки в visual studio code? А то приходится всё писать в так называемой "песочнице"

Comment: А в чем проблема создать index.html ?

Comment: напишите подробнее, что за песочница? это node.js или отладчик в браузере? чтобы вы хотели видеть в модуле для visual studio code (чего не хватает). возможно стоит поискать по ключевым словам на английском языке.

Comment: Может быть я не совсем корректно выразился, я хотел бы использовать все возможности в vs code, например, при обращении к полям объекта, знать, какие весть у него поля, а так приходится все писать наугад и проверять в браузере. 
Есть выход - проверять все в отладчике в chrome, там видно все поля и  методы объектов